# Get Selected files in Win Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to iterate on the files selected by the user when the batch command was called via the context menu of win explorer.

I've searched but haven't been able to find how to do it. So the question is: is it possible? If so, how to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by *call* a batch via the *context menu* of explorer? "Send to"?

Comment: In the code of the send to is what I need: You select the files you want to sent to and then you click on the container you want it to go. I wanna know what is the code to iterate on the select files that I suppose Send to uses.

Comment: "Send To" will invoke the shortcut with as many parameters as files are selected. So if your shortcut invokes your bat file, you will get your filenames as %1 %2 %3 ....

Answer (score 0):

The list of files that get passed in to your script will be stored in the `%*` parameter. To iterate through them without knowing how many there are, you can use this:

```
for %%A in (%*) do (
    <the rest of your code here, using %%A to represent each file>
)
```

If your code is too long to be wrapped in a for loop, you can write a second batch file that calls your initial code.

```
@echo off
for %%A in (%*) do call yourscript.bat %%A
```